# How to execute a loop for changing number of iterations in R

Tags: r, while-loop

I have a question function which takes a range and I need to execute a while loop for the give range. Below is the pseudo-code I wrote. Here I intend to read  files from a sorted list and, start = 4 and end = 8 would mean read files 4 to 8.

```
readFiles<-function(start,end){
    i = start
    while(i<end){
      #do something
      i += 1
    }
}
```

I need to know how to do this in R. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: would `lapply(mylist[start:end],function(x){do something}` be another approach?

Comment: If you replace `i=start` by `i<-start`, `i<end` by `i<=end`, and `i += 1` by `i<-i+1`, your pseudo-code should work.

Comment: Thank you very much @mra68 for your answer. It work fine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this :

```
readFiles<-function(start,end){
    for (i in start:end){
        print(i) # this is an example, here you put the code to read the file
# it just allows you to see that the index starts at 4 and ends at 8
    }
}

readFiles(4,8)
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 6
[1] 7
[1] 8
```

As pointed out by mra68, if you don't want that the functions does something if `end>start` you could do this :

```
readFiles<-function(start,end){
    if (start<=end){
        for (i in start:end){
            print(i) 
        }
    }
 }
```

It will not do anything for `readFiles(8,4)`. Using `print(i)` as the function in the loop, it is slightly faster than a `while` if `start<=end`and also faster if `end>start`:

```
Unit: microseconds
              expr     min       lq     mean   median      uq      max neval cld
  readFiles(1, 10) 591.437 603.1610 668.4673 610.6850 642.007 1460.044   100   a
 readFiles2(1, 10) 548.041 559.2405 640.9673 574.6385 631.333 2278.605   100   a

Unit: microseconds
              expr  min    lq    mean median    uq    max neval cld
  readFiles(10, 1) 1.75 1.751 2.47508   2.10 2.101 23.098   100   b
 readFiles2(10, 1) 1.40 1.401 1.72613   1.75 1.751  6.300   100  a
```

Here, `readFiles2` is the `if ... for` solution and `readFiles` is the `while` solution.

Comment: This is not 100% equivalent to the C-syntax in the question. Consider the case `end<start`.

Comment: Thank you very much @etienne for your answer. It work fine!